# Create Chart from a Table in Vaadin

Tags: java, charts, vaadin

I use Vaadin 7. I have a Table that is Editable. What I want to do is that when I click on a button I want to create a Chart with the values present in the Table. Is that possible in Vaadin ?

Answer (score 1):

Vaadin has all components you need.

The Table has some datasource which you can retrieve the values for the chart.
The Chart component allows you to draw the chart from a datasource.

So depending the chart and values you have this is simple.

Here is the link to the table component description

https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.table.html

And here is the link to the vaadin charts

https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/charts.html

Of course you must wire them together,
means on mouse click create a chart, read the values from the table and feed them to the chart.

Comment: I already saw all those components, the question was does Vaadin provide a way to build chart directly from an existing Table. But thanks anyway.

Comment: No, you have to do it yourself. Vaadin has no such automatic "conversion"